# stream does not append new line character

Tags: c++, io, fstream

I call the function `write` in a loop. I need to append several lines.

I pass

`std::fstream file(filename);`

to

`write(info, &file);`

The following code doesn't append new line character, or at least Notepad++ does not display it.(i get just a whitespace) :

```
void IO::write(const std::string& name, std::iostream* stream)
{
    (*stream) << "usr" << name << " === " << "\n";
}
```

What is wrong? How to append the new line to the text file?

Comment: Are you inspecting the file in Notepad++ after it's been flushed (or closed)? Have you tried other ways of checking for the newline (a hex editor, or file size)?

Comment: If your development environment is set up for UNIX line endings (or you opened the file in binary mode), and Notepad++ only supports Windows CRLF, then you won't see them. But, both sound unlikely to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on my rather harsh comment, there is nothing wrong with your newline, but...

...use the *correct* types...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

// ...
std::ofstream file( filename );
// ...
```

...and if you want to print `info` to the stream, just do it instead of going through some function...

```
// ...
file << "usr" << info << " === " << "\n";
// ...
```

...if you really *want* to make it a function, at least use references and the proper types...

```
void IO::write( std::ostream & stream, const std::string & name )
{
    stream << "usr" << name << " === \n";
}

// ...
IO::write( file, info );
// ...
```

...but the "traditional" way of doing output in C++ is to overload the `operator<<` for the class in question, and have the implementation for printing an instance sit right alongside the class member implementations instead of going through C-style functions...

```
class MyClass
{
    // ...
    friend std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & stream, const MyClass & obj );
    // ...
};

std::ostream & operator<<( std::ostream & stream, const MyClass & obj )
{
    stream << "usr" << obj.name << " ===\n";
    return stream;
}

// ...
MyClass mine;
file << "Hello\n" << mine << 42 << "\n";
```

Comment: I'm not in a mind to find out whether the dodgy use of `fstream` and pointers resulted in the borked output or if Notepad++ is to blame (which I don't have), but I didn't want to leave the OP without some good advise on how to do proper C++ I/O... feel free to give an answer more on the point.

Comment: I use a pointer because I need this to both work with -fstream- (I will use the correct type) and with stringstream. I can't use references AFAIK

Comment: The reason why I write functions is that this is the IO class and not some class that just needs `operator <<` and `>>` overloaded. But now I think that my IO class may as well overload `operator<<` and `>>`. Is it going to be a better way, I got it right?

Comment: @Oleksandra: Both `ofstream` and `stringstream` are derived from `ostream`. If they weren't, you would need a different overloadings of `operator<<()` to work, which would defeat the purpose. As for an IO class... that's what I wanted to point out: "I/O" of "Anything" is the business of "Anything", not the business of "I/O". That's the whole idea of object orientation: You don't have an I/O class doing the I/O for everything, because you'd need to extend that class every time you add something to your program.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend that you use std::endl rather than "\n". std::endl flushs the file, "\n" does not.

After file is flushed (std::endl used or file closed). Try different editors to be sure, but end of line should be visible.

Jean

Comment: Actually, `"\n"` *does* flush the file if it's set to line buffered, while `std::endl` *always* flushes the file even if it's set to fully buffered. Whether to use one or the other depends entirely on context.

Comment: @DevSolar There's no such thing as line buffered in C++.  You can set unit buffered, but using `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` is probably the best compromise for beginners.

Comment: @JamesKanze: You can't *set* output to line buffered, but the standard streams *are* synced to the C streams by default, which means they *are* line-buffered if attached to a terminal. (Check `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio()`). Add to this that virtually every C++ library implementation is based on C code... calling `std::endl` at the end of each line is as bad as calling `fflush()` after each `fprintf()` or `fwrite()`. Flush if you need to, and only then. That's not me talking, thats Bjarne and cppreference.com.

Comment: @DevSolar If the stream is synced with the C streams, then there is no difference between `std::endl` and `'\n'` for `std::cout` _if_ it is connected to an interactive device.  For a file, there is no guarantee that `stdout` be line buffered, and of course, line buffering doesn't exist for files you open yourself.  And if you don't know what you're doing, `std::endl` is the _safe_ option.  Arguably, using anything else is premature optimization; but if you understand what you're doing, it's usually more convenient to pop the `'\n'` into another string, without worrying about the missing flush.